# ＆lt;p&gt;

Tags: html

今日から始めましたけど、
`&lt;p&gt;`
って、何ですか？

Answer (score 3):

`<p>`ですね。

ＨＴＭＬの中にタグを表す文字列は書けないので、
文字参照と言われる表現で書きます。
`&`で始まり`;`で終わる形式でその間の部分は名前か数値(１０進形式`#nn`か１６進形式`#xhh`)で文字を表現します。
（ [参考リンク](http://w-d-l.net/html__entities/) ）

`&lt;`は、`<`
`&gt;`は、`>`
なので
`&lt;p&gt;`は、`<p>`を表すことになります。